# Error using eval, Undefined function or variable 'largeArrayDims'.

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm  want to install enceval toolkit on my Matlab2012a:

*[enceval toolkit file to install on Matlab](https://github.com/jackculpepper/enceval/blob/master/enceval-toolkit/featpipem_setup.m)*

I already installed the support compiler visual studio 10 and SDK 7.1. 
They had written this code in file.m to install :

```
archstr = computer('arch');
if(strcmp(archstr,'win64'))
  lapacklib = fullfile(matlabroot, ...
  'extern', 'lib', 'win64', 'microsoft', 'libmwlapack.lib');
  blaslib = fullfile(matlabroot, ...
  'extern', 'lib', 'win64', 'microsoft', 'libmwblas.lib');
  command =  'mex (''LLCEncodeHelper.cpp'', lapacklib, blaslib, largeArrayDims)';
elseif(strcmp(archstr,'win32'))
  lapacklib = fullfile(matlabroot, ...
 'extern', 'lib', 'win32', 'microsoft', 'libmwlapack.lib');
  blaslib = fullfile(matlabroot, ...
  'extern', 'lib', 'win32', 'microsoft', 'libmwblas.lib');
  command =  'mex(''LLCEncodeHelper.cpp'', lapacklib, blaslib)';
elseif strcmp(archstr,'glnx86')
    command = 'mex -O LLCEncodeHelper.cpp -lmwlapack -lmwblas';
elseif strcmp(archstr,'glnxa64')
    command = 'mex -O LLCEncodeHelper.cpp -lmwlapack -lmwblas -largeArrayDims';
else
    error('System architecture could not be identified');
end

mexCmds=cell(0,1);
mexCmds{end+1}=command;

for i=1:length(mexCmds)
  fprintf('Executing %s\n',mexCmds{i});
  eval(mexCmds{i});
end
```

when I run this code , I  get this exception :

```
*Executing mex ('LLCEncodeHelper.cpp', lapacklib, blaslib, largeArrayDims)

Error using eval

Undefined function or variable 'largeArrayDims'.

Error in featpipem_setup (line 32)

  eval(mexCmds{i});*
```

I don't know why it is problem of matlab version or there are something that is missing ?

Comment: Try compiling without the largeArrayDims option (should be default in your version anyway). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509010/

Comment: what's your value of `computer('arch')` ?

Comment: also, it looks like there are misplaced tildes (code demarcation symbols \`) following the statement `lineif(strcmp(archstr,'win64'))`, specifically here:
\`command =  'mex (''LLCEncodeHelper.cpp'', lapacklib, blaslib, largeArrayDims)'\`. Are they also in the original installation code?

Comment: the value for `computer('arch')` is win64

Comment: Yes, line `if(strcmp(archstr,'win64'))` it is already in original code. if u like to see the original file. it is available online  on : (https://github.com/jackculpepper/enceval/blob/master/enceval-toolkit/featpipem_setup.m)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing a string `'-largeArrayDims'` instead of variable `largeArrayDims` which is not declared anywhere prior to the call to mex, that is, try running the following:

```
lapacklib = fullfile(matlabroot, ...
  'extern', 'lib', 'win64', 'microsoft', 'libmwlapack.lib');
blaslib = fullfile(matlabroot, ...
  'extern', 'lib', 'win64', 'microsoft', 'libmwblas.lib');
command =  'mex (''LLCEncodeHelper.cpp'', lapacklib, blaslib, ''-largeArrayDims'')';
eval(command)
```

Comment: I test ur code on Matlab and I got an error :  `C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: 'largeArrayDims' not found. 
 
Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.`

Comment: One more try: use `'-largeArrayDims'` instead, that is: `command =  'mex (''LLCEncodeHelper.cpp'', lapacklib, blaslib, ''-largeArrayDims'')'`

Comment: @dawad: Glad to be of help. If this answers your question please check the mark next to the question - an uptick on the arrow is also appreciated.